# std::vector and pair in constructor appear to be 'empty'

Tags: c++, stdvector, std-pair

For some reason, my vector and pair containers are outputting '0' when run, and not the value of 'input'. Does it have to do with the way I declared the size of my containers? I am also not certain if I am using the emplace_back function properly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <vector> 
using namespace std;

class Graph {

    private:
    int n, h, input;
    vector< pair <int,bool> > couple;
    vector <int> vec; 

    public: 
    Graph(vector<int> getVec, int getN, int getH) : vec{move(getVec)}, n(getN), h(getH){  
    vec.resize(n*n);
    couple.resize(n*n);

    for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i){
        cin >> input;
        vec.push_back(input);
        couple.emplace_back(make_pair(vec[i], false));
        //  cout << vec[i];
        cout << couple[i].first;
    }
};

};

int main() 
{
    int N, H, input;
    cin >> N >> H;
    vector <int> vector;
    Graph g (vector, N, H);
}
```

Comment: `push_back` appends to the end of the vector. You resize the vector to the (wrong) size and then you append to the end of that (which obviously will not alter the first `n*n` entries)

Comment: `push_back` means to add another element to the end of your container. When you resized your vector, the elements are initialized to zero, which is what you are printing

Comment: Also it is not clear why you use size `n*n` instead of `n*h`, or why you would `move(getVec)` and then attempt to overwrite what you just moved in

Comment: `emplace_back()` is for constructing an element and inserting it. You already have the pair constructed using `make_pair()`, so you can directly insert the value with `push_back()`. You can also pass the values stored in the pair (`vec[i]` and `false`) to `emplace_back()`, which will forward them to the pair's constructor to construct the pair with those values.

Comment: When using I/O, I've found it better to gather the data first, then call the constructor.  Rather than having the I/O happen within the constructor.

Comment: It would appear that I hadn't realized the functional differences between push_back and std::cin. Thank you for clarifying!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in the constructor. After the resize you shouldn't have used push_back as the vectors are already inflated by the vector.resize().

```
Graph(vector<int> getVec, int getN, int getH) : vec{ move(getVec) }, n(getN), h(getH){
        vec.resize(n*n);
        couple.resize(n*n);

        for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i) {
            cin >> input;
            vec.at(i) = input;
            couple.at(i) = make_pair(vec[i], false);
            cout << couple[i].first;
        }
    };
```